# Adding custom fields to google calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-gsuite

I'm trying to add custom fields to google calendar (similar to description, guests). I need the fields to have custom text like company consent which will remain the same throughout all events/meetings. Is there a way that we can add such fields?

So far, I have looked into extended properties but I am not sure if that would be a solution as it states that,

> The Calendar API provides the ability to set hidden key-value pairs with an event, called extended properties. Extended properties make it easy to store application-specific data for an event without having to utilize an external database.

So, by my understanding, extended properties can only be used to store meta-information and not something that will reflect on google calendar on the UI.

I would really appreciate your help! Thank you!!

Comment: Have you considered workspace addons?

Answer (score 2):

Options

1. Use a web browser extension to inject your custom fields and the Google Calendar API and OAuth
2. Create your own UI

   - Use the Google Apps Script CardService to create and Google Workspace add-on
   - Use the Google Apps Script HTML Service to create a web app or a dialog / sidebar on Google Docs, Forms, Slides or Sheets
   - Use any other platform and the Google Calendar API and OAuth

Answer (score -1):

Simply storing custom fields through api will not show the fields in the calendar UI. You need to inject them as fields in the calendar UI through a Chrome Extension.

Exactly for this purpose we have developed a Chrome Extension "Custom Fields for Google Calendar" to easily create and update custom fields.

[Insert Custom Fields In Google Calendar Event](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/custom-fields-for-google/fgomfahnlnkadfcbnlbfddbdfhckbamm)

[Disclaimer]: We are the developer of Custom Fields Add-on.

Comment: According to some experiments I did, this extension does NOT edit the extended properties of the ics event hence downvote.