# How to create and inject custom fields into Google Calendar UI for certain users?

Tags: google-apps-script, events, google-calendar-api

I want to be able to edit the Google Calendar UI to have custom fields show up when a user is creating an event. I know it is possible to patch events and add custom fields to it after, but I want these custom fields to be defaulted on the user's calendar so anytime they create an event, the options show up. The pop-up I'm talking about is below.

[image]

I know that you can use AppScripts to create an add-on on the side of the screen, but I would prefer to have the change made right in the user's main UI. It *seems* like this is possible, as there is a Zoom add-on that allows you to "Make it a Zoom Meeting" as seen in the screenshot above in the bottom right hand corner.

If anyone could point me towards an example/documentation on how to do this, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding custom fields to google calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66537729/adding-custom-fields-to-google-calendar)

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66537729/adding-custom-fields-to-google-calendar)

Where a community member shared a few options such as:

1. Using a browser extension to inject your custom fields + the Google Calendar API + the OAuth required.
2. Create your own UI using [Google Apps Script CardService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service) and its [HTML service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html).